# My django project keeps blinking and loading

Tags: html, django

my project was working before but now that cleaned my cache it keeps blinking. It keeps loading with no end in sight. The table in my project appears and disappears again and again blinking. The navbar and thead are fine but my tbody keeps doing it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had `location.reload(true)` in my script that is why it was happening.

Answer (score -1):

This must be a problem with your IDE.
If you are using Pycharm, try clearing your cache by going to
**File > Invalidate Caches**.

If that fails, uninstall your IDE and re-install it again.